# Attrib is not recognized?

Tags: php

When I run this command `attrib *. -h -s`, it shows `*attrib is not recognized as an internal or external command*`. . How can I solve this? Pls tel me about the solutions?..

Comment: `exec("attrib *. -h -s") ` ?

Comment: I've never heard of the `attrib` command before. What is it? Are you sure your server has it?

Comment: are you using windows server? if yes see if you can execute same thing from command prompt, most probably attrib is not in your run path, so command is not visible to php

Comment: @icktoofay: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATTRIB The error message comes from Windows Command Prompt. HRK's comment about paths is most likely correct.

Answer (score 2):

very simple way:
1 search attrib.exe in th window search box ->Copy the attrib the .exe into location where you want to execute the command ->
then simply fire your command.

It will Work definatly